# Activity does not get executed after Catching error in Orchestration

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-durable-functions

```
let a = null;
try {
    a =  yield context.df.callActivityWithRetry("Some1Activity", retryOptions, obj);
}
catch(error){
    context.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    yield context.df.callActivityWithRetry("Some2Activity", retryOptions, obj2);
    throw new Error(error);
}
```

My problem is when error occurs, `Some2Activity` does not get executed. Though it is mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling).

I even tried this

```
let a = null;
let errorObj = null;
try {
    a =  yield context.df.callActivityWithRetry("Some1Activity", retryOptions, obj);
}
catch(error){
    context.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    errorObj = error;
}

if(errorObj !== null) {
    yield context.df.callActivityWithRetry("Some2Activity", retryOptions, obj2);
    throw new Error(error);
}
```

It did not work.
what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `durable-functions: ^1.1.0`. It has a [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/issues/23). After upgrading to `durable-functions: ^1.1.1` it got fixed.